# How to clean and standardize a large number of words in a column?

Tags: r

I have a column in a dataframe that has 600 words. I need to standardize the misspelled words. For example, I want " alpha", "alpha", "alpha school" and "ALPHA" to become "Alpha". I want "bravo", " bravo ", "braVO", and "bravo bravo" to become "Bravo".

Here is a short example of my dput.

```
structure(list(names = structure(c(2L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 11L, 10L), .Label = c(" alpha", "alpha", "Alpha", "ALPHA", 
"alpha school", "alpha_school", "bravo", "Bravo", "charlie Charlie", 
"DELTA", "delta school"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses the adist (approximate string distance) function in base R.

```
vals <- c('Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie', 'Delta')

match <- function(x){
    vals[which.min(adist(x, vals))]}

df$standardName <- sapply(df$names, match)

             names standardName
1            alpha        Alpha
2            alpha        Alpha
3     alpha_school        Alpha
4     alpha school        Alpha
5            ALPHA        Alpha
6            Alpha        Alpha
7            bravo        Bravo
8            Bravo        Bravo
9  charlie Charlie      Charlie
10    delta school        Delta
11           DELTA        Delta
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `mutate`, `str_detect` and `if_else` statements. This gives you a little more control over which patterns you want to look for.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

data <- tibble(names = c(" alpha", "alpha", "Alpha", "ALPHA", 
                         "alpha school", "alpha_school", "bravo", "Bravo", "charlie Charlie", 
                         "DELTA", "delta school")) 

words <- c(Alpha = "^ ?[aA]",Bravo = "^ ?b",Charlie = "^ ?c",Delta = "^ ?[dD]")


for(i in seq_along(words)){
  data <- data%>%
    mutate(names = if_else(str_detect(names,words[i]),
                           names(words)[i],names))
}
```